# i want to get data from another website and display it on mine but with my style.css

Tags: php

So my school has this very annoying way to view my rooster.
you have to bypass 5 links to get to my rooster.

this is the link for my class (it updates weekly without changing the link)

https://webuntis.a12.nl/WebUntis/?school=roc%20a12#Timetable?type=1&departmentId=0&id=2147

> i want to display the content from that page on my website but with my
>   own stylesheet.

i don't mean this:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

or an iframe....

Comment: if its just for personal use, use Greasemonkey

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be better done using jquery and ajax. You can get jquery to load the target page, use selectors to strip out what you need, then attach it to your document tree. You should then be able to style it anyway you like.

Comment: do you have a tutorial for me?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably read the whole page into a string variable (using file_get_contents like you mentioned for example) and parse the content, here you have some possibilities:

- Regular expressions
- Walking the DOM tree (eg. using PHPs DOMDocument classes)

After that, you'd most likely replace all the style="..." or class="..." information with your own.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the cURL library: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

But you have to extract part of the page you want to display, because you will get the whole HTML document.

Comment: How is this related to the question? He doesn't ask **how** to get the contents but to parse / re-style them.

Comment: [What is an implicit question?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120201172336AA68dnj) He actually states "I don't mean this: [code that just gets the html and outputs it]", your answer is practically the same.